# How to look up if a value exists in a column whose header matches a value in another cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I've tried using VLOOKUP and HLOOKUP but I'm not finding the solution.

For simplicity:

I want to highlight a cell in B2 **IF** its value is found in column φ

1. Column φ falls within a specified range (D1:F in the example)
2. The value in cell φ1 is equal to A2

<s>It’s a bit late, so I didn't make the spreadsheet in markdown yet. I'll add that tomorrow if necessary.</s> All help appreciated.

**Update... Here's an example of what success would look like:**

[image]

Comment: Share a sample workbook with few sample data. Your question little bit confusing.

Comment: Done, sorry was super tired last night!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this Conditional Formatting in B2

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(E1:Z,,MATCH(B2,E1:Z1,0)),A2)
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. It's a little different than I am looking for. I was so tired last night, but now I've added an example if you could please look at that

Comment: Just anchor it and apply to the whole B2:B: =COUNTIF(INDEX(E$1:Z,,MATCH(B2,E$1:Z$1,0)),A2)

Comment: Ah, I see how to fix it… =COUNTIF(INDEX(E$1:Z,,MATCH(A2,E$1:Z$1,0)),B2) works. Just A and B swapped. Thanks so much! I'll mark this as the answer

Comment: You're right, wasn't looking in your new example the order of columns but that it was an array. Great that you could sort it out!

Answer (score 2):

Try this [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule for the range `B2:B`:

```
=countif($E$1:$Z, A2)
```